# SQL Server Select from multible tables with join, where condition and group by

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, conditional-statements

is there a correct way to select from more than 2 tables with join and a condition then group by

the idea is to select the shown fields and it works but the problem is when i add the condition some how from the join code it gets me less result which i have more results that apply to the condition

such as the following code in sql server as a stored procedure :

```
SELECT [PAYMENTCOLLECT].[Pay_ID]
      ,[PAYMENTCOLLECT].[Pay_type]
      ,[PAYMENTCOLLECT].[Pay_date]
      ,[PAYMENTCOLLECT].[Paid]
      ,[PAYMENTCOLLECT].[Total_Pay]
      ,[PAYMENTCOLLECT].[Pay_remains]
      ,[VOLT].[Volt_Name]
      ,[CUSTOMERS].[C_NAME]
      ,[PAYMENTCOLLECT].[Pay_Note]
      ,[CUSTOMERS].[C_TEL]
      ,[CUSTOMERS].[C_EMAIL]
      ,[CUSTOMERS].[ID_COSTOMER]


  FROM [dbo].[PAYMENTCOLLECT]

full outer JOIN CUSTOMERS
on CUSTOMERS.ID_COSTOMER=PAYMENTCOLLECT.ID_COSTOMER
full outer JOIN VOLT
on VOLT.Volt_ID=PAYMENTCOLLECT.Volt_ID


  where [PAYMENTCOLLECT].[Total_Pay] > [PAYMENTCOLLECT].[Paid]
  and CONVERT(nvarchar,Pay_ID)+CONVERT(nvarchar,Pay_type)+CONVERT(nvarchar,Paid)+CONVERT(nvarchar,Total_Pay)+C_NAME+CONVERT(nvarchar,C_TEL)+CONVERT(nvarchar,C_EMAIL)+CONVERT(nvarchar,MEMO) like '%' + @Criterion + '%'
```

Comment: you can add a group by at the end of this query.  Without some idea of what kind of input/output you expect, it's hard to give a real answer, however.  Usually you would do inner joins over a normal OLTP schema unless you want to show customers without payments (and then you would use left outer).  So, it is legal to full outer join, but it may be semantically not what you want...

Comment: the idea is to select the shown fields and it works but the problem is when i add the condition some how from the join code it gets me less result which i have more results that apply to the condition

Comment: outer joins will return NULL where a row doesn't match. When you compare anything to NULL (in your WHERE clause), it won't return anything. I suggest you look at your own data in detail and take note of what the actual missing rows are. Do you have a good understanding of why you are using `full outer join` instead of say `left join` or `inner join`?

Comment: You need to create tables, put in sample data...and then discuss the expected output.  That is the best way to ask for help.

Comment: Dear Nick, yeah there are null values in the rows that are shown in result which mean it works, actually all the rows has the null value in the note field so, the null values ain't the case here i think.